# jQuery Button Timer Qeustions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am messing around with jQuery and I am trying to make a timer. I got everything set and I thought I had the buttons set up correctly, but the Start Timer and Reset Timer buttons do not work. The Stop Timer button works fine. Can someone point me in the right direction. I went through some old posts and tried a few things but I still cannot get it to work. Here is all my code below. Thank You

```js
var hour = 12;
var minute = 10;
var second = 10;
var meridies;


function formatTime(time) {
  hour = time.getHours();
  if (hour>12) {
    hour = hour-12;
    meridies = "PM";
  } else {
    meridies = "AM";
  }
  minute = time.getMinutes();
  if (minute<10) {
    minute = "0"+minute;
  }
  second = time.getSeconds();
  if (second<10) {
    second = "0"+second;
  }
  return hour+":"+minute+":"+second+" "+meridies;
}

$("#reset").on('click',function() {
    $(".results").addClass("hidden");
    $("#reset").addClass("hidden");
    $("#start").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#time_started").addClass("hidden");
    $("#time_ended").addClass("hidden");
  });
  
  var start_time;
var formatted_time;
var end_time;
var formatted_end_time;
var time_change;



$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#start").on('click',function() {
    $("#start").addClass("hidden");
    $("#stop").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#time_started").addClass("hidden");
    $("#time_ended").removeClass("hidden");
    end_time = new Date();
    start_time = new Date();
    formatted_time = formatTime(start_time);
    
  });

  $("#stop").on('click',function() {
    $("#stop").addClass("hidden");
    $("#reset").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#time_started").addClass("hidden");
    $("#time_ended").removeClass("hidden");
    end_time = new Date();
    formatted_end_time = formatTime(end_time);
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You started at "+formatted_time+".</p>");
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You finished at "+formatted_end_time+".</p>");
    time_change = end_time-start_time;
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You counted "+(time_change/1000)+" seconds.</p>");
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You are off by "+(time_change/1000-45)+" seconds.</p>");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 200px auto 0;
    max-width: 900px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  div {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  
  .hiddden {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Timer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="scripts/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/format.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/reset.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/times.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text">
        <p>
          Can you internally count 45 seconds precisely?
        </p>
      </div>
      <button id="start">Start Timer</button>
      <button id="stop" class="hidden">Stop Timer</button>
      <button id="reset" class="hidden">Reset Timer</button>
      <span id="time_started" class="hidden">Timer Started</span>
      <span id="time_ended" class="hidden">Timer Ended</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hide` and `show` methods instead like so and it will work as you intended

```js
var hour = 12;
var minute = 10;
var second = 10;
var meridies;


function reset() {
  $(".results").hide();
  $("#reset").hide();
  $("#start").show();
  $("#stop").hide();
  $("#time_started").hide();
  $("#time_ended").hide();
}

function formatTime(time) {
  hour = time.getHours();
  if (hour>12) {
    hour = hour-12;
    meridies = "PM";
  } else {
    meridies = "AM";
  }
  minute = time.getMinutes();
  if (minute<10) {
    minute = "0"+minute;
  }
  second = time.getSeconds();
  if (second<10) {
    second = "0"+second;
  }
  return hour+":"+minute+":"+second+" "+meridies;
}

$("#reset").on('click',reset);
  
var start_time;
var formatted_time;
var end_time;
var formatted_end_time;
var time_change;

reset();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#start").on('click',function() {
    $("#start").hide();
    $("#stop").show();
    $("#time_started").hide();
    $("#time_ended").hide();
    end_time = new Date();
    start_time = new Date();
    formatted_time = formatTime(start_time);
    
  });

  $("#stop").on('click',function() {
    $("#stop").hide();
    $("#reset").show();
    $("#time_started").hide();
    $("#time_ended").show();
    end_time = new Date();
    formatted_end_time = formatTime(end_time);
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You started at "+formatted_time+".</p>");
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You finished at "+formatted_end_time+".</p>");
    time_change = end_time-start_time;
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You counted "+(time_change/1000)+" seconds.</p>");
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You are off by "+(time_change/1000-45)+" seconds.</p>");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 200px auto 0;
  max-width: 900px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.hiddden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text">
  <p>
    Can you internally count 45 seconds precisely?
  </p>
</div>
<button id="start">Start Timer</button>
<button id="stop">Stop Timer</button>
<button id="reset">Reset Timer</button>
<span id="time_started" class="hidden">Timer Started</span>
<span id="time_ended" class="hidden">Timer Ended</span>
```